# Rails and SQL appending string to database field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

We have a table:

```
id____|_____name
1     |    john
2     |    jane
```

What is the best way to append some string to name column, resulting in

```
     id___|___name
     1    |   john doe
     2    |   jane doe
```

Extra question: When using sql CONCAT for that purposes does it require the same computational cost as for retrieving data and than saving it (table.find(1)->.name = name + "doe"->.save), or (how does CONCAT work? Does it first read field and than uses UPDATE or appending it without retrieving?)?

> edit

i've found `increment_counter` method wich makes atomic increment, well is there any similar method for atomic string appending, I mean the one that will append it in one transaction. Or what is the best way to update log field?

Comment: what is the DB you are using ?

Comment: Without reading, how can you do modification and update?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586373/using-rails-update-to-append-to-a-text-column-in-postgresql

Comment: Please be kind to check my question after edit. I'll use mysql, but postgres based anwer wil be welcome also.

Comment: It will do a single "update" request, but within the guts of the dbms code the update action may be doing lots of different things.  Do you really need to know what's happening, internally, in your dbms when you do an update?

Comment: btw the sql request would be `update mytable set name = concat(name, " doe");`

Comment: If your question is "Is loading things into an ActiveRecord object in rails, and then saving it out again slower than just doing a raw sql query and not instantiating any objects" then the answer is "Yes, of course, it's much slower, how could it not be?"

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there any rails method performing `update mytable set name = concat(name, " doe");` or I should do it as a raw query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postgres

```
Model.update_all("name = name || doe")
```

In Mysql

```
Model.update_all("name = concat(name, 'doe')")
```